# How to fetch a single object from Coredata using a predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to fetch a single object from my coredatabase, however it keeps returning null. My method is based off another method which returns every value from the coredata object that I am accessing..

I have never tried this before and have tried reading apples documents but its just not making sense.. this is what my method looks like

```
- (NSMutableArray *)readSelectedInstall:(NSString *)projIDString {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (context == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Nil");
    }
    else {


        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"InstallProject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ProjID==%@", projIDString];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error;

        NSMutableArray *installProjectDictionaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (InstallProject *installProj in fetchedObjects) {

            NSMutableDictionary *tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.companyName forKey:@"CompanyName"];
            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.projNo forKey:@"ProjNo"];
            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.projID forKey:@"ProjID"];

            [installProjectDictionaryArray addObject:tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray];
        }

        return installProjectDictionaryArray;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

any help getting me to return a single item thats projID matches the projIDString would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `context == nil`? Or does `executeFetchRequest` return `nil`? In the latter case, what is the value of `error`?

Comment: turns out I wasnt allocating my CoredataManagins class.. I have done that now and am reciving an error. "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (ANY ProjID CONTAINS[cd] "10000085")'"

Comment: "ANY ProjID CONTAINS[cd] ..." is not the predicate that you showed in your question ...

Comment: Whoops.. i used the error from the answer below. this is what my code from above generates. "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath ProjID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity InstallProject id=2>'"

Comment: That means that you did not define an attribute "ProjID" for the Core Data entity "InstallProject". Perhaps a small typo?

Comment: OHHhhhhh... Okay so I thought ProjID was supposed to represent the xml parameter I have.. which is declared with a captial P... then I just clicked that its supposed to represent the coredata var, which cannot be declared with capitals.. so changed to projID.. BOOM worked.. oh man.. sorry for the hassle.. wow cant belive my code worked LOL, I only clicked after you mentioned typo.. and i was like ProjID how hard is it to spell? LOL then lightbulb moment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Import NSManagedObject(InstallProject) and fetch one object like this,

```
-(InstallProject *)readSelectedInstall:(NSString *)projIDString
{

    NSArray *fetchedObjects;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"InstallProject"  inManagedObjectContext: context];
    [fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
    [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY ProjID contains[cd] %@)",projIDString]];
    NSError * error = nil;
    fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    if([fetchedObjects count] == 1)
    return [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    else
    return nil;  

}
```

Comment: okay, figured out i wasnt initalising my coredatamanaging class and after doing so this is what your code returned "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (ANY ProjID CONTAINS[cd] "10000085")'"

Comment: okay directly use [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ProjID==%@", projIDString] or try, [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ProjID CONTAINS %@",name]];

Comment: You should replace the IF ELSE at the end and simply return [fetchedObjects firstObject]. If there's no object in the array, it will return nil for you.

Answer (score 16):

What about the `fetchLimit` on the `fetchRequest` You can set that to *1*

> The fetch limit specifies the maximum number of objects that a request should return when executed.

E.g. in Swift:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cart")
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Cart.creationDate), ascending: true)]
```

**Edit:** The `sortDescriptors` are set only because I was using this `fetchRequest` with an NFRC, you can just execute the `fetchRequest` too:

```
do {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cart")
  fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
  fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", mainCart)
  var objects: [Cart]
  try objects = mainMoc.execute(fetchRequest) as! [Cart]
} catch {
  
}
```